# RHEL4 PHP5 CGI Internal Server Error with SugarCRM 5.5

Tags: php5, rpm, rhel4

I'm running an RHEL4 server with Apache 2.0, and I need PHP 5.2.1 - 5.2.11 for SugarCRM Pro 5.5.0. I also need to run it side-by-side with another version of PHP, so I compiled it from source for CGI. Problem is, I keep getting an Internal Server Error only on certain pages:

> [Tue Jan 19 20:53:53 2010] [error] [client 69.106.58.53] *** glibc detected *** double free or corruption (out): 0x008df858 ***, referer: https:// (removed for privacy) /index.php?action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index
>
> [Tue Jan 19 20:53:53 2010] [error] [client 69.106.58.53] Premature end of script headers: php-cgi-5.2.11, referer: https:// (removed for privacy) /index.php?action=Login&module=Users&login_module=Home&login_action=index

I've also tried running "sudo up2date --update", and tested every version of PHP from 5.2.1 to 5.2.12 with no luck.

This is what my PHP configuration looks like:

> make clean && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.2.11 --enable-fastcgi --enable-force-cgi-redirect --enable-discard-path --enable-mbstring --with-libxml-dir --with-pear --with-curl --with-openssl --with-kerberos --with-zlib --with-mysql --with-pdo-mysql --with-imap --with-imap-ssl && make && sudo make install

What should I do at this point? Is there an RPM somewhere that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is old but i think is better providing a solution if has been discovered.

I have solved simply setting the environment variable MALLOC_CHECK_ explicitly to 0:
setenv MALLOC_CHECK_ 0

in the [RHEL4 Documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Release_Notes/as-zseries/)docs is explained the cause of the problem (in the section Package Specific Notes / glibc).